# Users deleting their first questions after they have been answered -- can the question be recovered?

Tags: discussion, support

Here is what happened:

A new user asked his first question. The question was not that bad. I helped that user so when he did added info via comments, he edited the question until it had enough detail to be answered properly.

My answer was rather long, with all possibilities covered, even code samples, and even thourough explanations.

Obviously, it helped that user, because when I was in the subway this morning, browsing with the new SO iPad app, I got notified he commented "Damn! Yeah that was it! Thanks!".

Back at my desktop, the question and everything was gone. The OP obviously had deleted the question meanwhile.

Yes I know that the user might have deleted his question because he did not know better, even though this is hard to believe, considering all the guidelines SO offers in various ways.

Unfortunately, I don´t remember the user´s name, so I cannot locate him in the user listings.

My question is:

**Is it possible to recover the question, and related info?**

Furthermore, **how can I prevent this from happening again** (except for ignoring all new user´s questions in the future, which would not help anyone)?

Comment: It can be voted for undeletion by appropriately privileged users if we had a URL, or the user's ID.

Comment: Did this actually happen or is this more hypothetical?  I'm not seeing a deleted answer in your history.

Comment: It did happen. On SO. Question was about Eval and Execute in vbscript.

Comment: @TheBlastOne Do you have the link?

Comment: No. From where? Well I´ll search my history.

Comment: @TheBlastOne I'm looking through your history and you've got no recently deleted answers.

Comment: @TheBlastOne I've been through your answer history as well, we can see all your deleted answers.  There are none that meet the criteria you give us above; and only four that were deleted as a result of question deletion.

Comment: Strange. And no deletion yesterday, or today? Really strange. I wish I had a screenshot.

Comment: I found it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422676/pass-a-string-as-a-variable-name-qtp. This question was definetely not listed in the list of answers I gave, and the second answer is not in the inbox notification list, but it used to be this morning. Am I messing everything up?

Comment: That question was never deleted by anybody, please check the revision history http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27422676/revisions

Comment: The activity tab of my user now lists everything about this answer. This too was different this morning. Really! I looked where I looked now, and it wasn't there. 
Anyway, issue solved. (But we don´t know what was going on, do we?) What should I do with my meta question? Delete?

Comment: Sunshine I agree. It looks fine now. But it was gone previously. Really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the four answers you've posted that were deleted by the question being deleted:

- [Need a listing of the hp QTP resellers/distributors in the US](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807680/need-a-listing-of-the-hp-qtp-resellers-distribuors-in-the-us/4053270#4053270)
- [Best IT Related Acroynm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131729/best-it-programming-technology-related-acronym/5673824#5673824)
- [I want two animations at a time.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857896/i-want-2-animation-at-a-time/12857989#12857989)
- [What is the difference between | and || (or & and &&)? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214169/what-is-the-difference-between-and-or-and/12214216#12214216)

Comment: Thanks. It´s not one of those. It is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422676/pass-a-string-as-a-variable-name-qtp, and it (if you ask me) re-appeared.

Comment: @TheBlastOne I think your eyes are playing tricks on you, that's never been deleted.

Comment: I am close to thinking that, too. I don´t do drugs, though. And I really checked twice, and more. That´s why I came up with this question at meta.

Comment: I´ll accept this answer because there is nothing in my hands proving what I saw, or believe to have seen. So instead of getting more attention, I´ll accept. (I also voted close-prim-opinion-based, because I am the only one believing it was gone.)